# Dealing with float precision problems (testing collisions with SAT)

Tags: java, collision-detection, floating-point-precision

I'm looking for advices about tracking float precision leaks (a tricky bug ?). The following code results in false positives for very close objects.

Shape is an interface for handling convex meshes and Shape.getRange computes some dot products.

```
public class SAT
{
  public static boolean areRangesOverlapping( float[] range0, float[] range1 )
  {
    if( range0[1] < range1[0] )
      return false;

    if( range1[1] < range0[0] )
      return false;

    return true;
  }

  public static boolean areShapesColliding( Shape shape0, Matrix4 shapeMatrix0, Shape shape1, Matrix4 shapeMatrix1 )
  {
    float[] range0 = new float[ 2 ];
    float[] range1 = new float[ 2 ];

    Matrix4 shape0To1 = new Matrix4()
      .inverse( shapeMatrix0, 1e-3f )
      .multiply( shapeMatrix1 );

    Matrix4 shape1To0 = new Matrix4()
      .inverse( shapeMatrix1, 1e-3f )
      .multiply( shapeMatrix0 );

    Matrix3 normal0To1 = new Matrix3()
      .setRotationAndScale( shape0To1 )
      .inverse( 1e-3f )
      .transpose();

    Matrix3 normal1To0 = new Matrix3()
      .setRotationAndScale( shape1To0 )
      .inverse( 1e-3f )
      .transpose();

    Vector3 center0 = shape0.getCenter();

    Vector3 center1 = new Vector3()
      .fromP3toR3( new Vector4()
        .multiply( shape0To1, new Vector4( center0, 1.f ) )
      );

    for( int i = 0; i < shape0.getCount(); ++i )
    {
      Vector3 direction0 = shape0.getDirection( i );

      Vector3 direction1 = new Vector3()
        .multiply( normal0To1, direction0 );

      shape0.getRange( center0, direction0, range0 );
      shape1.getRange( center1, direction1, range1 );

      if( !areRangesOverlapping( range0, range1 ) )
        return false;
    }

    center1 = shape1.getCenter();

    center0 = new Vector3()
      .fromP3toR3( new Vector4()
        .multiply( shape1To0, new Vector4( center1, 1.f ) )
      );

    for( int i = 0; i < shape1.getCount(); ++i )
    {
      Vector3 direction1 = shape1.getDirection( i );

      Vector3 direction0 = new Vector3()
        .multiply( normal1To0, direction1 );

      shape0.getRange( center0, direction0, range0 );
      shape1.getRange( center1, direction1, range1 );

      if( !areRangesOverlapping( range0, range1 ) )
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Thank's

PS :

It wasn't a float precision problem but a big mistake. I forgot to handle the edge-to-edge case. Anyways replacing all floats by doubles provided some good hints for solving the problem.

Here's the solution :

```
public class SAT
{
  public static boolean areRangesOverlapping( float[] range0, float[] range1 )
  {
    if( range0[1] < range1[0] )
      return false;

    if( range1[1] < range0[0] )
      return false;

    return true;
  }

  public static boolean areShapesColliding( Shape shape0, Matrix4 position0ToW, Shape shape1, Matrix4 position1ToW )
  {
    float[] range0 = new float[ 2 ];
    float[] range1 = new float[ 2 ];

    Matrix4 position0To1 = new Matrix4()
      .inverse( position1ToW, 1e-3f )
      .multiply( position0ToW );

    Matrix4 position1To0 = new Matrix4()
      .inverse( position0To1, 1e-3f );

    Matrix3 normal0To1 = new Matrix3()
      .setRotationAndScale( position0To1 )
      .inverse( 0.f )
      .transpose();

    Matrix3 normal1To0 = new Matrix3()
      .setRotationAndScale( position1To0 )
      .inverse( 0.f )
      .transpose();

    // Face-to-face, Face-to-edge
    //
    Vector3 center0 = shape0.getCenter();

    Vector3 center1 = new Vector3()
      .fromP3toR3( new Vector4()
        .multiply( position0To1, new Vector4( center0, 1.f ) )
      );

    for( int i = 0; i < shape0.getFaceCount(); ++i )
    {
      Vector3 direction0 = shape0.getFaceDirection( i );

      Vector3 direction1 = new Vector3()
        .multiply( normal0To1, direction0 );

      shape0.getRange( center0, direction0, range0 );
      shape1.getRange( center1, direction1, range1 );

      if( !areRangesOverlapping( range0, range1 ) )
        return false;
    }

    center1 = shape1.getCenter();

    center0 = new Vector3()
      .fromP3toR3( new Vector4()
        .multiply( position1To0, new Vector4( center1, 1.f ) )
      );

    for( int i = 0; i < shape1.getFaceCount(); ++i )
    {
      Vector3 direction1 = shape1.getFaceDirection( i );

      Vector3 direction0 = new Vector3()
        .multiply( normal1To0, direction1 );

      shape0.getRange( center0, direction0, range0 );
      shape1.getRange( center1, direction1, range1 );

      if( !areRangesOverlapping( range0, range1 ) )
        return false;
    }

    // Edge-to-edge
    //
    center0 = shape0.getCenter();    

    center1 = new Vector3()
      .fromP3toR3( new Vector4()
        .multiply( position0To1, new Vector4( center0, 1.f ) )
      );

    for( int e0 = 0; e0 < shape0.getEdgeCount(); ++e0 )
    {
      Vector3 edge0 = shape0.getEdgeDirection( e0 );

      for( int e1 = 0; e1 < shape1.getEdgeCount(); ++e1 )
      {
        Vector3 edge1 = new Vector3()
          .multiply( normal1To0, shape1.getEdgeDirection( e1 ) );

        Vector3 direction0 = new Vector3()
          .cross( edge0, edge1 );

        Vector3 direction1 = new Vector3()
          .multiply( normal0To1, direction0 );

        shape0.getRange( center0, direction0, range0 );
        shape1.getRange( center1, direction1, range1 );

        if( !areRangesOverlapping( range0, range1 ) )
          return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Matrix inversion is quite susceptible to precision problems, so that may be the source of the issues you see.

Comment: Well I tried to test the inversion. A random matrix inverted 16 times multiplied with a unit vector leads to an error under 1e-6 (compared to the same matrix without inversion).

Answer (score 2):

First idea would be to increase the accuracy by using `double`s instead of `float`s.

Comment: If using doubles don't reduce the problem, can I be sure this isn't precision problem ?

Comment: I don't understand all of your code and what algorithms you are applying, but if still double is giving not the expected results, then it might be a problem in your algorithm. What are some example numbers you use?

Comment: No, you can't be sure that it isn't a precision problem.  Doubles have all the same problems that floats do.

Comment: Of course, David is right. But I write all my gaming algorithms in floats and I have never problems. So I think (but I'm of course not sure, since I don't see any example numbers) that there is a problem in your logic.

Comment: Well about 0.01 for testing a unit sphere against another (low tessellation).

Comment: If I understood correctly that you are trying to determine wether two spheres of radius 1 (or 0.5) are colliding with each other if their edges are closer than 0.01 to each other, then both floats and doubles should definitely do the job correctly.

Comment: Agreed...If doubles don't change anything, this increase the probability of a bug. Anyways, getting advices on tracking precision leaks can be useful.

Comment: Are they spheres?  If the shapes that you're trying to detect collisions between are spheres, then all the stuff with matrix inversion and ranges is probably overkill.  Just calculate the square of the distance between the centres of the two spheres, which you can do with only multiplication and addition, and compare it with the square of the sum of the radii of the spheres.  This should be extremely fast.

Comment: +1 dont forget that you need to compare with an error.  The use of double can reduce the error by 10^9 but the error check is still needed.

Comment: I'm not sure how comparing with an error would help.  We're not doing an equals here, we're doing less than or greater than.  Introducing an error term to the comparison would just make the result even less accurate - replacing LHS - RHS > 0 with LHS - RHS > 0.001, for example.

Comment: @DavidWallace No the shapes are general meshes. I just give one of my error example.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare floats you have to choose some "tolerance precision".
You can read about that problem [here](http://if-programmer.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/how-to-compare-floats-safely.html)

I meant this:

```
final float TOLERANCE = 0.00001f;

if (range1[0] - range0[1]  > TOLERANCE)
    return false;

if (range0[0] - range1[1] > TOLERANCE)
    return false;
```

Comment: I'm not testing equality. Where would you add any epsilon ?

Comment: Not sure the required epsilon is constant. However I can use this hack if I can't find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BigDecimal` if you have decimal numbers and you want to avoid precision problems.  Otherwise, regardless of whether you have `float` or `double`, you'll always have difficulties with comparisons, and with certain arithmetic operations.

Comment: @sylvain then you are already doomed, because in Java there are a lot of things that hurt performance and cannot be avoided.

Comment: BigDecimal will also have precision problems for real world situations because you can not display or measure to infinite precision.